# How does one access a derived classes member variables from within the superclass in Tcl?

Tags: oop, object, tcl

Code:

```
package require TclOO

oo::class create Supe {
    variable cape boots

    constructor {} {
        puts -nonewline "Supe: "
        puts [info class variables [self class]]
    }
}

oo::class create Clark {
    superclass Supe

    variable glasses suit

    constructor {} {
        puts -nonewline "Clark: "
        puts [info class variables [self class]]
        next
    }
}

set hero [Clark new]
```

Output:

```
Clark: glasses suit
Supe: cape boots
```

Is it possible to get a list of Clark's member variables from within Supe's constructor without passing them into Supe as an argument?

Ultimately, the goal is to dynamically set derived class variables from a dict argument:

```
foreach {varName} [info class variables [self class]] {
    variable $varName [dict get $args $varName]
}
```

If the above code can be used in the superclass constructor, it would avoid putting it in each derived class constructor.

Comment: Are you looking for `[info class variables [info object class [self]]]`?

Comment: Whaddya know? I thought I tried that, but it works.

Comment: The place where this will become more complicated is when there is three level inheritance. There needs to be some better way of doing the discovery of "properties" defined by the class hierarchy but I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: @DonalFellows, are you referring to getting the 2nd level's properties in the base class? That would seem to be problematic, unless there's a way to extract that class name, too, and merge with the 3rd-level variable list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the object with `self object`, or just `self`. You can then get the class of the object with `info object class`. And finally, you can get the member variables of a class with `info class variables`.

Putting it all together results in:

```
[info class variables [info object class [self]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

My take does not add to the answer already given, but looks at the motivating problem of the OP:

> Ultimately, the goal is to dynamically set derived class variables
>   from a dict argument:

What I have been using in the past to batch-update an object's state is sth. along the lines of:

```
oo::class create C {
  variable a b
  constructor {aDict} {
    my variable {*}[lsort -unique [my lookupVars [info object class [self]]]]
    # dict with aDict {;}
    lassign [dict values $aDict] {*}[dict keys $aDict]
  }

  method lookupVars {currentClass} {
    set v [info class variables $currentClass]
    foreach scl [info class superclasses $currentClass] {
      if {$scl eq "::oo::object"} {
        break
      }
      lappend v {*}[my lookupVars $scl]
    }
    return $v
  }

  method print {} {
    foreach v [info object vars [self]] {
      my variable $v
      puts "<$v> [set $v]"
    }
  }
}
```

The key items are:

- `lookupVars` is a naturally recursive implementation walking the class, direct, and indirect superclasses to collect of defined per-class variables. This follows up on what Donal describes as a discovery of "properties". Note that this is limited in several ways (e.g., mixins are ignored, also TclOO's internal linearisation scheme is not reflected, no control for duplicates etc.)
- `lassign` can be used to set multiple variables at once. Alternatively, but with some side effects, [`dict with`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M27) "loads" a given dict's content into variables available for the current scope. [`my variable ?varName ...?`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/object.htm#M13) will provide method-local links to the collected per-class variables. This way, you save a script-level loop and don't have to filter the provided dict for unmatched keys.

Watch:

```
oo::class create D {
  superclass C
  variable c d
}

oo::class create E {
  superclass D
  variable e f
}


[D new {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4}] print
[E new {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 f 5 e 8 x 3}] print
[D new {a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 f 5 x 3}] print
```

Comment: @Donal: For TclOO, it would be a great addition to have class and object introspection that is aware of and reveals the actual linearisation. NX (XOTcl, likewise) has [`/obj/ info precedence`](https://next-scripting.org/2.3.0/doc/nx/api/Object/man#27) and for convenience [`/obj/ info lookup variables`](https://next-scripting.org/2.3.0/doc/nx/api/Object/man#17) for this purpose (and equivalents when departing from an object's class).

Comment: I updated the example to use `lassign` rather than `dict with`. Is also faster in my micro-benchmarks.

Comment: I agree that those capabilities would be nice. (Not sure about the names!) The problem with using the `variables` slot is that really just does resolver control; having a variable name in it doesn't make it useful to configure that var from outside. I need to add another slot... and dream up what the semantics of the slot's contents is too. The introspectors (which will support a `configure` method I guess) will come out of that. This might be my Christmas project this year...